# Can't activate Plugin: unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION

Tags: plugins, errors

I'm writing a plugin but have a problem.

I wanted to make an upload form for my existing plugin, so I don't need to upload every picture with the Media Uploader and Copy&Paste the URL in the form.

I used this tutorial: [Tutorial](http://www.webmaster-source.com/2013/02/06/using-the-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-your-plugin-or-theme/)

Now, when I wanted to install the updated Plugin I get the following error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION in /var/www/intern/wpkkbk/wp-content/plugins/widget-plugin.php_/widget-plugin.php on line 133

The code I added looks like this (line 133: `add_action(...)`):

```
function my_admin_script($hook) {
    if ($hook != 'widgets.php')
        return;


        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', plugins_url('widget-plugin.php_/js/upload.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_script');
```

I don't know, where I made a mistake. It didn't even work, when I used the exact same code from the tutorial. Any suggestions!

Comment: Check your brackets inside `wp_register_script()` - it's a typo.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably due to an unclosed curly brace somewhere. Can include more code? The line numbers in the error message are not always where the actual issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Your path have an extra `_` in between `widget-plugin.php` and `/js/upload.js`.

BTW, your path should just be

```
plugins_url( '/js/upload.js' , __FILE__ ),
```

Go and check the following

- [`wp_enqueu_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts)
- [`wp_enqueue_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)
- [`wp_register_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script)
- [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

Answer (score 0):

With the new Wordpress version, the jQuery library is already added.
You can review the [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function.

Othersie, I think here the issue is your link.
You need to review the [plug-in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) urls.

```
function my_admin_script($hook) {
    if ($hook != 'widgets.php')
        return;
        wp_enqueue_media();
        wp_register_script('my-admin-js', plugins_url('/js/upload.js', dirname(__FILE__)), array('jquery'));
        wp_enqueue_script('my-admin-js');

}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_script');
```

Comment: jQuery has been included in WordPress since Lord knows when. Pretty much for ever. Ironically, you might want to "review the [wp_register_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) function" - especially its third parameter.

Comment: Took the words out of my mouth.